# What does MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (10973, 0) mean？How can I resolve it？

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using MediaPlayer play a mp3 file what was copied to my cache directory from another.It post a "10973 warning".

Comment: If you don't have any problems, you can just ignore this warning. Some native components have a load of trash logs, that should be ignorred

Comment: But it can not work when the warning is post

Answer (score 8):

I have the same warning in my logcat every time I start playing new audio file. This is a fragment of verbose log:

> ```
> V/MediaPlayerNative: prepareAsync
> V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=200, ext1=10973, ext2=0
> W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (10973, 0)
> V/MediaPlayerNative: callback application
> V/MediaPlayerNative: back from callback
> V/MediaPlayerNative: message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
> V/MediaPlayerNative: MediaPlayer::notify() prepared
> ```

[Here](https://github.com/pandalion98/SPay-inner-workings/blob/master/boot.oat_files/arm64/dex/out0/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) I found:

```
public static final int MEDIA_INFO_NO_VIDEO = 10973;
```

As you can see audio file is prepared correctly. The warning seems to be only info saying that file has no video. In my case it's obvious because I'm playing only audio files.

At first I related the warning with my audio lag problem but further investigation showed something different.